# Can blow drying be beneficial for hair and scalp health?

Tags: medical-science, hair

My friend told me that blow drying hair can prevent hair loss and dandruff by making the skin dry and thus making it harder for funghi and yeasts to flourish. This sounds reasonable, but for a man with short hair at room temperature it takes about 30 minutes for hair to dry on its own. Can this 30 minutes make a difference? Has this problem been studied scientifically?

From googling, I got the impression that blow hair drying is always detrimental to hair. However I am interested to see if there are trade-offs.